# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, inflate-exception

I have a very frustrating error. The application was running just fine till yesterday, I closed android studio then when I opened it today it showed this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication11, PID: 29530
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication11/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment class was not set
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination.getClassName(FragmentNavigator.java:322)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:158)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1057)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:637)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:590)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:555)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:537)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2685)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2236)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2009)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1965)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(Frag
```

The activity_main layout  in which this error is popping up is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


// This is the line 22 in error

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" >
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to point out that the third line in error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication11/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

this part "{com.example.myapplication11/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}". I dont know why it shows myapplication11 here my apps name is just myapplication... my application11 was an old project I was working on so is it related to that?
My activitymain.kt file is

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.onNavDestinationSelected
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Gradle build (MODULE) file is

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication11"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Gradle build file (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    ext.nav_version = "2.3.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In your activity_main.xml file..

**Change:**  `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"`

**To:** `class = "androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"`

Comment: Still no use after changing it to class

Comment: If it was fine the other day as you stated, So try closing and reopening SDK

Comment: so i also tried to close and reopening the SDK, it still gives me the same error

Comment: Instantiate your fragment programatically using FragmentManager

Comment: I donot know how to do that. I am not from a programming background I am a biomedical engineer this is for my final year project. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFeedFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: It might actually sound bizarre but I just copied the whole code, made a new project, pasted the the old code in the new project and BOOM! It worked ahaha

Comment: Congrats! Good to know that